# Read cookie text value in a Python Bottle application

Tags: python, cookies, bottle

I am trying to figure out how cookies work in a Python [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) application. Please be kind as I am pretty new to Python. How do I read a value out of the cookie that I have set?

Example:

```
@route('/cookie_setpage/')
def settingcookie():
    response.set_cookie('Cookie_name','Some value')
    return 'Set!'

@route('/cookie_readpage/')
def testingcookie():
    r=request.get_cookie('Cookie_name')
    return str(r)
```

When I do this I get the text "None" as return, which seems to be the default value or something. How am I suppose to access the text 'Some value' from the cookie got with `get_cookie`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Your solution

`bottle` does not send a path along with the cookie if you don't specify it, which means that the browser is in charge of deciding which `path` to use for the cookie (for some reason, the bottle docs state something else).

(If you don't know what the path is, read the other title in this answer).

[RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) (search for "Interpreting Set-Cookie") states that **the default path for a Cookie is the path that generated the cookie** — `/cookie_setpage`, in your case.

This of course means the cookie is not being sent to `/cookie_readpage`.

To solve that, just define a path when you set the cookie:

```
response.set_cookie('Cookie_name','Some value', path='/')  # Your entire site.
```

### What is cookie path?

The path is an attribute of the cookie.

The browser will only send a cookie to pages that are "below" the path for the cookie.

So, if you set your cookie path to `/cookie_setpage`, then `/cookie_setpage/cookie_readpage` gets the cookie, but `/cookie_readpage` doesn't.

if you set it to `/`, then any page gets it, because it's your site's root.